# laravel 5.3 not interpreting index.php

Tags: php, apache, laravel, centos, composer-php

I am new to laravel and was able to code a project on windows 7. i am using laravel 5.3.

I am looking to deploy the project to my dedication cloud server which is running centos 6.8.

I am unable to get the laravel landing page to diplay which is the same page that you get when you initially create a laravel project.

I have installed composer on the centos server and the composer command is recognized globally. Laravel was installed to /var/www/laravel.

**APACHE Version**
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 18 2016 15:24:00
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9

**PHP version**
php -v
PHP 7.0.11 (cli) (built: Sep 15 2016 09:38:31) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.11, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Laravel Version
laravel -V
Laravel Installer version 1.3.3

Composer installed in /bin/composer

Laravel Key generated and added to /var/www/laravel/.env

httpd.conf is default

I am rather new to laravel and deploying. can someone give me a detailed explanation of what needs to be modified so that the project can be available in the cloud.

Apache runs fine currently.

Comment: What *does* display? Did you configure your `httpd.conf` to point at `/var/www/laravel/public`?

Comment: What ceejayoz said and also make sure you have Laravels default .htaccess file in the /public folder that sets up the front controller to route every request to index.php

Comment: I have now pointed it to /var/www/laravel/public and copied the project files into the directory. making use of virtual host through the vhosts on conf.d

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and it seems to be working now.

> http://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/

Great link for 5.3 working with Ubuntu but the commands can be modified to use Yum instead and in place of nginx making use of apache.

Thank you for the advises CeeJoz and Rob Fonseca

I upgraded from php 5.* to php 7 (see link below)
I done a

> yum remove php*

Then followed below instructions

> https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/